# Python Library For Adding Up To 999999999 Days To a Given Date

Tags: python, date, calendar

I'm doing a programming exercise in which I have to add N days to a given date where N can be up to 999999999 and the given date is before the year 3000 using Python. Are there any libraries other than `datetime` that can do this?

I know Java has a library which could do this for large values of N but with Python, I only found a library called `datetime` but the problem with it is that 1. It's too slow for large values of N and 2. Since N could be up to 1000000000, the date value would be out of range.

Comment: Is a date even meaningful at that point?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's just a programming exercise(Competetive programmig). I'm just doing ad hoc problems and this is one of them.

Comment: I don't think any lib would support years over 2*10^6... I think it's more of a manual task - competitive programming is mostly about smart thinking and fast code than custom libs.

Comment: @h4z3 Yeah I was thinking I should write it myself but Java has a library for that so I though maybe so does python

Comment: I think any thinkable date (as a whole date, not just year) is within datetime's limit. Seriously, that's up to the last day of year 9999! I don't think we need over 2.5 *million* years of exact dates...

Comment: @h4z3 Yeah, they probably could have come up with better ideas for problems related to date. Anyway, I though I would just turn the date to days, then add N and finally, turn the result back into a date.

Comment: Found it! Python's `time` can deal with years in that range! You might want to check the documentation for better functions, but e.g. using `ctime`: if you get a timestamp of the given_date, add `N*seconds_in_day` and pass it to `time.ctime`, you will get your result (as a full timestamp).

Comment: @h4z3 Wow! Thank you so much! You may want to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.date` supports up to the end of year 9999. That seems like enough... but 10^9 days is over 2.5 *million* years.

Another Python lib dealing with time is called just `time` which works mainly with C time functions.

What I found is that `time.ctime()` gets the time in seconds from epoch (argument defaults to current time in that format - `time.time()`) and outputs a default formatted time string.

You can parse given time using `time.strptime()` to get a time struct, then convert it to epoch seconds with `time.mktime()`. Then add your N days as seconds. And voila! You have a seconds from epoch for the time you want.

That way, lib only deals with parsing and converting, but math is done on ints.

Test for the current time (without parsing it), N=10^9:

```
>>> test = time.time()
>>> print(test)
1561378571.5154927
>>> time.ctime(test)
'Mon Jun 24 14:16:11 2019'
>>> test_after_N = test + 10**9 * 24 * 3600
>>> print(test_after_N)
86401561378571.52
>>> time.ctime(test_after_N)
'Sun Jun 27 13:16:11 2739926'
```

If you need another format, you might want to parse or cut the output or find whether it's possible to alter the default format.

Module documentation can be found here - https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html